# CSS/HTML form: button alignment wrong in IE and Opera

Tags: html, css, forms, cross-browser

I am currently stuck with a weird alignment problem in my HTML form.
in Firefox/Chrome/Konqueror the layout is just fine - see below

[image: Layout in FireFox]

But in IE8 and Opera the layout looks like this:

[image: Layout in IE]

My HTML looks like this

```
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#3d4144" id="jobs">
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>          
    <td style="text-align: center;">Please login to post a job.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>
   <div id="stylized" class="myform">
     <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="loginproc.php">
      <label>Username:
      <span class="small">Enter your e-mail</span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      <label>Password:
      <span class="small">Enter your password</span>
      </label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
      <button type="submit">Login</button>       
     </form>                 
  </div>​
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="body" href="register.php" style="text-decoration: none">If you are not registred yet, you can signup here (free of charge)!</a>
</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

and my CSS looks like this

```
#stylized input{
float:left;
font-size:10px;
font: normal Verdana,sans-serif;
padding:5px 2px;
border:solid 1px #2B578A;
width:200px;
margin:2px 0 10px 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#stylized input[type="password"]{
float:left;
font-size:10px;
font: normal Verdana,sans-serif;
padding:5px 2px;
border:solid 1px #2B578A;
width:200px;
margin:2px 0 10px 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


#stylized label {
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
float: left;
width: 10em;
margin-right: 1em;
text-align: right;
width:140px;
}

#stylized .small{
color:#666666;
display:block;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:normal;
text-align:right;
width:140px;
}

.myform{
margin:0 auto;
width:400px;
padding:14px;
}

#stylized button{
clear:both;
margin-left:160px;
width:120px;
height:25px;
text-align:center;
line-height:20px;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:bold;
background:#414549;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
border: 0px solid #2B578A;
}

#stylized button:hover{
background:#2B578A;
color:#FFFFFF;
border: 0px solid #2B578A;
}
```

The problem begins as soon as I put the form into a table (which I do for some design purposes).

Comment: Here's a fiddle for debugging purposes: http://jsfiddle.net/XNpKa/.  IE8 and FF both look like the first example from what I can see.

Comment: Your label has 2 widths stated for some reason (width: 10em; && width:140px;). Not sure if that would be the issue though.

Comment: Looks the same to me in IE8 as in Firefox

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Obviously there are some other things in my CSS file (for the style of the page) that influences the position of my button as I still have the same problem - even after debugging with jsfiddle. Will post an update...

Comment: Ok, when I only add the form to a page it is shown as it is supposed to. But when I add the form to my page with menu and other styles, the layout is shown incorrect in IE and Opera. So at least I know that the code for form as such is correct. Thanks all!

Comment: I have just updated my HTML code above. As soon as I put the form into a table the button is not shown correct in IE and Opera. Any idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div align="center">
```

That's the culprit. Either remove that or set "text-align:left" on the element surrounding your submit button.